# How to parse a response.body okhttp

Tags: android, rest, okhttp

I've a problem with parse a string result by okhttp response and I want to parse this string but I don't know a way to do it.
Can anyone help me?

I'm using android studio.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
    private TextView mTextViewResult;
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
        mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);
 
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
 
        String url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";
 
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
 
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
 
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    final String myResponse = response.body().string();
 
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mTextViewResult.setText(myResponse);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> Block quote
> [{"attributes": {"message": "Here are some resources to get started:\n\n - [Configuring Home Assistant](https://home-assistant.io/getting-started/configuration/)\n - [Available components](https://home-assistant.io/components/)\n - [Troubleshooting your configuration](https://home-assistant.io/docs/configuration/troubleshooting/)\n - [Getting help](https://home-assistant.io/help/)\n\nTo not see this card popup in the future, edit your config in\n`configuration.yaml` and disable the `introduction` component.", "title": "Welcome Home!"}, "context": {"id": "840e4ec2072144cfa7d53550796dc35d", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "persistent_notification.notification", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:04.942593+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:04.942593+00:00", "state": "notifying"}, {"attributes": {"azimuth": 282.29, "elevation": 37.79, "friendly_name": "Sun", "next_dawn": "2019-04-15T05:35:52+00:00", "next_dusk": "2019-04-14T18:24:46+00:00", "next_midnight": "2019-04-15T00:00:05+00:00", "next_noon": "2019-04-15T12:00:13+00:00", "next_rising": "2019-04-15T05:56:50+00:00", "next_setting": "2019-04-14T18:03:50+00:00"}, "context": {"id": "a8908c263c854345a518358553319876", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "sun.sun", "last_changed": "2019-04-14T05:57:06.013733+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-14T15:26:30.009359+00:00", "state": "above_horizon"}, {"attributes": {"attribution": "Weather forecast from met.no, delivered by the Norwegian Meteorological Institute.", "entity_picture": "https://api.met.no/weatherapi/weathericon/1.1/?symbol=10;content_type=image/png", "friendly_name": "yr Symbol"}, "context": {"id": "e2d38361a1704e2a97a78dca780e2e20", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "sensor.yr_symbol", "last_changed": "2019-04-14T14:31:00.098478+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-14T14:31:00.098478+00:00", "state": "10"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "potenza massima stufa", "last_triggered": null}, "context": {"id": "708bfbddda494f07a11506b5e69e3add", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "script.1547400071844", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:27.871225+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:27.871225+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "potenza minima stufa", "last_triggered": null}, "context": {"id": "9721b6341250436e8050556e44015ebd", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "script.1547305398108", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:27.872132+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:27.872132+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"device_class": "connectivity", "friendly_name": "Remote UI"}, "context": {"id": "4429627581ef481785396af892bb92cc", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "binary_sensor.remote_ui", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:27.901163+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:27.901163+00:00", "state": "unavailable"}, {"attributes": {"access_token": "6304d62742f4b9792101bdb83ee7a7953c1263bc7276e42e6b4f5c6b8a579253", "entity_picture": "/api/camera_proxy/camera.front_window?token=6304d62742f4b9792101bdb83ee7a7953c1263bc7276e42e6b4f5c6b8a579253", "friendly_name": "Front Window", "supported_features": 0}, "context": {"id": "53ddda3891f24b2b88ecedf43d27186a", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "camera.front_window", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:27.911773+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-14T15:22:32.548799+00:00", "state": "idle"}, {"attributes": {"auto": true, "entity_id": ["script.1547400071844", "script.1547305398108"], "friendly_name": "all scripts", "hidden": true, "order": 0}, "context": {"id": "d0230ccfddf4407fab7e784b3539fa3b", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "group.all_scripts", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:27.914874+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:27.914874+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"commands_encoding": "Base64", "device_code": 1000, "friendly_name": "Tv Sala da Pranzo", "manufacturer": "Samsung", "supported_controller": "Broadlink", "supported_features": 3512, "supported_models": ["UE40F6500"]}, "context": {"id": "a6dd1bd45e6e48338fd5d22246a27b48", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "media_player.tvsalotto", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:27.995463+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:27.995463+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Riscaldamento al massimo", "icon": "mdi:radiator"}, "context": {"id": "6c12c666d4df4b26a08ec20ea6769489", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.riscaldamento_massimo", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:27.996785+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:27.996785+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Porta Studio", "icon": "mdi:door"}, "context": {"id": "4ce7d589575b419b84f6b8bf7a2cd1d8", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.porta_studio", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:27.998025+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:27.998025+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Porta Ingresso", "icon": "mdi:door"}, "context": {"id": "946c2c4bf6774a75b5b387738670c623", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.porta_ingresso", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:27.999169+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:27.999169+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Movimento Salotto9", "icon": "mdi:security-account"}, "context": {"id": "4923466b5c9a4d0e8e9e9143f42a926a", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.movimento_salotto9", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.000306+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.000306+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Movimento Salotto2", "icon": "mdi:security-account"}, "context": {"id": "8314408ca4154fbcb717cd931fd81a44", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.movimento_salotto2", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.001453+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.001453+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Allarme Totale", "icon": "mdi:alarm-light"}, "context": {"id": "f6e8df0876134847b58c26a1e04c768c", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.allarme_inserito", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.002440+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.002440+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Movimento Salotto8", "icon": "mdi:security-account"}, "context": {"id": "2d7c89058b85494980d47181ff0e5fa2", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.movimento_salotto8", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.003254+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.003254+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Movimento Salotto3", "icon": "mdi:security-account"}, "context": {"id": "d64679da21464decb5c850b5e8c8337f", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.movimento_salotto3", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.004103+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.004103+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Allarme Notturno", "icon": "mdi:alarm-light"}, "context": {"id": "5be17c7837e948ecbf6249c71c101756", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.allarme_notturno_inserito", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.004916+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.004916+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Movimento Salotto7", "icon": "mdi:security-account"}, "context": {"id": "8f5e0deaa7664312b81268b7c37c6ca4", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.movimento_salotto7", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.005613+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.005613+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Movimento Salotto4", "icon": "mdi:security-account"}, "context": {"id": "2e3fb03b63364ef7854fae397f3fc0cb", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.movimento_salotto4", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.006301+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.006301+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Movimento Salotto6", "icon": "mdi:security-account"}, "context": {"id": "a53871f915a94afa82d963fc3919f9fe", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.movimento_salotto6", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.006999+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.006999+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Movimento Salotto5", "icon": "mdi:security-account"}, "context": {"id": "c8531835897942da9006338c41a2dcb8", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.movimento_salotto5", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.007795+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.007795+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Movimento Salotto1", "icon": "mdi:security-account"}, "context": {"id": "8ff65a959e284df7bc2ab212feddef43", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.movimento_salotto1", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.008593+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.008593+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Movimento Salotto", "icon": "mdi:security-account"}, "context": {"id": "2743ddd129ac46fa8e8301c5a8ffd2ad", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.movimento_salotto", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.009284+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.009284+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Porta Terrazzo", "icon": "mdi:door"}, "context": {"id": "942ae296eb984f4e95aad36f0d58060b", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.porta_terrazzo", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.009986+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.009986+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Porta Balcone", "icon": "mdi:door"}, "context": {"id": "8f3ab0b57dc84e74870f8bd25be344df", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.porta_balcone", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.010830+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.010830+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Porta Bimbi", "icon": "mdi:door"}, "context": {"id": "0349ed4a9a5640eab08700c95acb7300", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.porta_bimbi", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.011848+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.011848+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Porta Bagno", "icon": "mdi:door"}, "context": {"id": "ec8cdbc049ba45b39001d70d36e90e80", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.porta_bagno", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.013939+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.013939+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Riscaldamento Max/Min", "icon": "mdi:hot-tub"}, "context": {"id": "54770f9b1d6144ad9895dc7a5110ae2c", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.potenza_stufa", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.015161+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.015161+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Porta Letto", "icon": "mdi:door"}, "context": {"id": "44f37bd1e830460c93a9e2b8e4dcc562", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.porta_letto", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.016018+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.016018+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Buonanotte", "icon": "mdi:weather-night"}, "context": {"id": "71d91d353ae24fb783edf8447d9eb816", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "input_boolean.buonanotte", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.016736+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.016736+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"commands_encoding": "Base64", "current_temperature": null, "device_code": 1060, "fan_list": ["low", "mid", "high", "auto"], "fan_mode": "mid", "friendly_name": "Cmeretta AC", "last_on_operation": "cool", "manufacturer": "LG", "max_temp": 30, "min_temp": 18, "operation_list": ["off", "heat", "cool", "auto", "dry", "fan"], "operation_mode": "off", "supported_controller": "Broadlink", "supported_features": 4289, "supported_models": ["R09AWN", "R24AWN", "E09EK"], "target_temp_step": 1, "temperature": 20}, "context": {"id": "415929712c804d41a59535267467a55e", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "climate.cmeretta_ac", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.018072+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.018072+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"commands_encoding": "Base64", "current_temperature": null, "device_code": 1101, "fan_list": ["auto", "night", "low", "lowMedium", "medium", "mediumHigh", "high", "powerful"], "fan_mode": "low", "friendly_name": "Salotto AC", "last_on_operation": "heat", "manufacturer": "Daikin", "max_temp": 30.0, "min_temp": 18.0, "operation_list": ["off", "auto", "dry", "cool", "fan", "heat"], "operation_mode": "heat", "supported_controller": "Broadlink", "supported_features": 4289, "supported_models": ["FTXS20LVMA", "FTXS25LVMA", "FTXS35LVMA", "FTXS46LVMA", "FTXS50LVMA", "FTXS60LVMA", "FTXS71LVMA", "FTXS85LVMA", "FTXS95LVMA"], "target_temp_step": 1.0, "temperature": 28}, "context": {"id": "6983bd558bfa4d3aacf315093e751b2f", "parent_id": null, "user_id": "ecc652675a024d2fa17de965f2b758e5"}, "entity_id": "climate.salotto_ac_2", "last_changed": "2019-04-13T21:07:14.011233+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-13T21:07:51.760284+00:00", "state": "heat"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Riscaldamento al massimo off", "id": "1546977979696", "last_triggered": "2019-03-15T00:31:33.759146+00:00"}, "context": {"id": "4b58de64188e4db69a567fbb9b0d9ccb", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "automation.riscaldamento_al_massimo_off", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.891361+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.891361+00:00", "state": "on"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Stufa Potenza al minimo", "id": "1547401156274", "last_triggered": "2019-03-15T00:31:27.848705+00:00"}, "context": {"id": "69f610d7f8e34d51872a150d2976f92a", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "automation.stufa_potenza_al_minimo", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.897480+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.897480+00:00", "state": "on"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Startup Notification", "id": "7482bc2efbf740f78fb4170aba403f55", "last_triggered": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.978668+00:00"}, "context": {"id": "6fb93349693d43918b0aad3f28cc1cd4", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "automation.startup_notification", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.906247+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.979756+00:00", "state": "on"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Stufa Potenza al Massimo", "id": "1547401206250", "last_triggered": "2019-03-15T00:28:35.425947+00:00"}, "context": {"id": "461029cd27bc4d7b8ea69ed6e07f5a9e", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "automation.stufa_potenza_al_massimo", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.912871+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.912871+00:00", "state": "on"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Sync Google Home", "id": "1551485840564", "last_triggered": "2019-04-11T22:44:39.446583+00:00"}, "context": {"id": "b19fd4e189e6494fa01d9996d49c6687", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "automation.sync_google_home", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.918581+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:39.447259+00:00", "state": "on"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Riscaldamento al massimo on", "id": "1546977516568", "last_triggered": "2019-03-15T00:28:41.383403+00:00"}, "context": {"id": "7ca9a3abb253460f874395f83ae46af9", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "automation.riscaldamento_al_massimo_on", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.924212+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.924212+00:00", "state": "on"}, {"attributes": {"auto": true, "entity_id": ["automation.riscaldamento_al_massimo_off", "automation.riscaldamento_al_massimo_on", "automation.startup_notification", "automation.stufa_potenza_al_massimo", "automation.stufa_potenza_al_minimo", "automation.sync_google_home"], "friendly_name": "all automations", "hidden": true, "order": 1}, "context": {"id": "702f50f2068741a589f2ef90d695c5d1", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "group.all_automations", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.953809+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.953809+00:00", "state": "on"}, {"attributes": {"effect_list": ["blue_fade", "blue_strobe", "colorjump", "colorloop", "colorstrobe", "cyan_fade", "cyan_strobe", "gb_cross_fade", "green_fade", "green_strobe", "purple_fade", "purple_strobe", "rb_cross_fade", "red_fade", "red_strobe", "rg_cross_fade", "white_fade", "white_strobe", "yellow_fade", "yellow_strobe", "random"], "friendly_name": "led letto", "supported_features": 149}, "context": {"id": "26e38cbd1a9e4539a0c15184cb96e3f1", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "light.led_letto", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.890393+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.890393+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Chromecast", "supported_features": 21437}, "context": {"id": "622ebdf42c9c4385aba11b0ead8a2ba9", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "media_player.chromecast", "last_changed": "2019-04-14T14:03:36.408724+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-14T14:03:36.408724+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Google home mini", "supported_features": 21437}, "context": {"id": "4d310fe44cba4a1aa4818f5f8a48f17e", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "media_player.google_home_mini", "last_changed": "2019-04-14T02:30:04.840943+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-14T02:30:04.840943+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"auto": true, "entity_id": ["light.00828041b4e62d5c5b98", "light.32787642b4e62d621c0d", "light.led_letto", "light.20578840cc50e34e906f"], "friendly_name": "all lights", "hidden": true, "order": 2}, "context": {"id": "d1e4a1746a6149f2af8c215953635f29", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "group.all_lights", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:28.911301+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.824706+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"device_id": "1000549784", "friendly_name": "Audio 1", "rssi": -35}, "context": {"id": "7f2ef0d2229146f7802473b9990dd7fc", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "switch.sonoff_1000549784_1", "last_changed": "2019-04-14T09:23:27.244186+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-14T15:22:37.015952+00:00", "state": "on"}, {"attributes": {"device_id": "1000549784", "friendly_name": "Audio 4", "rssi": -35}, "context": {"id": "ddf58a8694b64ad4b3db65b12a073b6a", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "switch.sonoff_1000549784_4", "last_changed": "2019-04-14T09:23:33.499192+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-14T15:22:37.018065+00:00", "state": "on"}, {"attributes": {"device_id": "1000549784", "friendly_name": "Audio 2", "rssi": -35}, "context": {"id": "422f327e15554cc594c741b8139eec1f", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "switch.sonoff_1000549784_2", "last_changed": "2019-04-14T09:23:41.644737+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-14T15:22:37.014715+00:00", "state": "on"}, {"attributes": {"device_id": "1000549784", "friendly_name": "Audio 3", "rssi": -35}, "context": {"id": "6c4583d9cea943009d71a2089989eb07", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "switch.sonoff_1000549784_3", "last_changed": "2019-04-14T09:23:47.606677+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-14T15:22:37.017017+00:00", "state": "on"}, {"attributes": {"message": "The following components and platforms could not be set up:\n\n - sonoff.sensor\n\nPlease check your config.", "title": "Invalid config"}, "context": {"id": "d20f246e9417435ca51c556863d456eb", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "persistent_notification.invalid_config", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:35.112518+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:35.112518+00:00", "state": "notifying"}, {"attributes": {"auto": true, "entity_id": ["switch.sonoff_1000549784_1", "switch.sonoff_1000549784_2", "switch.sonoff_1000549784_3", "switch.sonoff_1000549784_4", "switch.70014205c44f33859ce7_1", "switch.70014205c44f33859ce7_2", "switch.70014205c44f33859ce7_3", "switch.70014205c44f33859ce7_7", "switch.78487660840d8e89c5c5", "switch.404847023c71bf236b37"], "friendly_name": "all switches", "hidden": true, "order": 3}, "context": {"id": "c8fdc50e2ef146d0beb6c3cdba6e12b6", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "group.all_switches", "last_changed": "2019-04-14T09:23:27.251808+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-14T09:23:27.251808+00:00", "state": "on"}, {"attributes": {"access_token": "c55c723edf0b85dd54962fbffbdc018864d5af84b2db4472bbbc7e155b8eee91", "entity_picture": "/api/camera_proxy/camera.onvif_camera?token=c55c723edf0b85dd54962fbffbdc018864d5af84b2db4472bbbc7e155b8eee91", "friendly_name": "ONVIF Camera", "supported_features": 0}, "context": {"id": "a713a6b59f9b4fb2adda6a1f32941b54", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "camera.onvif_camera", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:37.879996+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-14T15:22:32.547773+00:00", "state": "idle"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "comodino ", "supported_features": 17}, "context": {"id": "8cb8b68a8f19492990896e7cd7bb1753", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "light.32787642b4e62d621c0d", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.801549+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.801549+00:00", "state": "unavailable"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "RGB Led", "supported_features": 19}, "context": {"id": "a02d62d5f683469390dbf5162c4b0628", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "light.00828041b4e62d5c5b98", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.803512+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.803512+00:00", "state": "unavailable"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "scrivania filippo", "supported_features": 19}, "context": {"id": "d0ffe21f5d9743f39504af1d5bcb4ae6", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "light.20578840cc50e34e906f", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.805453+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.805453+00:00", "state": "unavailable"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "tv Filippo"}, "context": {"id": "a3eac8a4b6344cd89ed0524bc587160c", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "switch.404847023c71bf236b37", "last_changed": "2019-04-14T09:23:41.643461+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-14T09:23:41.643461+00:00", "state": "on"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Switch 3"}, "context": {"id": "78b4caa4b7fe42a981a564addaccfa46", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "switch.70014205c44f33859ce7_3", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.809387+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.809387+00:00", "state": "unavailable"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Switch 2"}, "context": {"id": "eb7c8a0f29e3461bb542ccee0be97ff3", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "switch.70014205c44f33859ce7_2", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.811297+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.811297+00:00", "state": "unavailable"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "scaldaletto"}, "context": {"id": "e56ccbe189e94cdeb6da4ccd5fddef5a", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "switch.78487660840d8e89c5c5", "last_changed": "2019-04-14T09:35:04.885554+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-14T09:35:04.885554+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Switch 1"}, "context": {"id": "b4560597da9945a0839312f1f6eb45ba", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "switch.70014205c44f33859ce7_1", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.815400+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.815400+00:00", "state": "unavailable"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Switch 7"}, "context": {"id": "b76e97a7fb2d44c2b237a6e70c2285ef", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "switch.70014205c44f33859ce7_7", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.817389+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T22:44:38.817389+00:00", "state": "unavailable"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Samsun TV salotto", "supported_features": 18233}, "context": {"id": "5d25a73d6ca5455bb09724dfe6bda2d6", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "media_player.samsungsalotto", "last_changed": "2019-04-14T13:43:45.020455+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-14T13:43:45.020455+00:00", "state": "off"}, {"attributes": {"friendly_name": "Update Available", "release_notes": "https://www.home-assistant.io/latest-release-notes/"}, "context": {"id": "ca231b332d9943268ba730dd058f49da", "parent_id": null, "user_id": null}, "entity_id": "updater.updater", "last_changed": "2019-04-11T23:44:29.314457+00:00", "last_updated": "2019-04-11T23:44:29.314457+00:00", "state": "0.91.3"}]

> Block quote

Comment: Can you please edit your question to explain what you mean by "parse", maybe by providing sample input and output?

Comment: The response contains many information but not suddivided I want to extract on a in formation with ID, state and other information.

Comment: can you show the response string  that you have got from request.

Comment: Is a response by request okhttp that contain a json with all devices and relative states

Comment: Could you please paste your code and tell exactly where you are facing problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `Gson` parser. The link is [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Now, the document about how to deal with your string is [here](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md)

First,Through your request,The result is

```
{
    "page": 2,
    "per_page": 3,
    "total": 12,
    "total_pages": 4,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "first_name": "Eve",
            "last_name": "Holt",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "first_name": "Charles",
            "last_name": "Morris",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/stephenmoon/128.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "first_name": "Tracey",
            "last_name": "Ramos",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/bigmancho/128.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Second.Declare one class like this

```
    public class ResponseResult {

    private int page;
    private int per_page;
    private int total;
    private int total_pages;
    private List<DataBean> data;

    public int getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(int page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public int getPer_page() {
        return per_page;
    }

    public void setPer_page(int per_page) {
        this.per_page = per_page;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public int getTotal_pages() {
        return total_pages;
    }

    public void setTotal_pages(int total_pages) {
        this.total_pages = total_pages;
    }

    public List<DataBean> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<DataBean> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public static class DataBean {
        private int id;
        private String first_name;
        private String last_name;
        private String avatar;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getFirst_name() {
            return first_name;
        }

        public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
            this.first_name = first_name;
        }

        public String getLast_name() {
            return last_name;
        }

        public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
            this.last_name = last_name;
        }

        public String getAvatar() {
            return avatar;
        }

        public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
            this.avatar = avatar;
        }
    }
}
```

and then,In your retrofit response.try use `Gson`parse the `String`,like as below.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ResponseResult responseResult=gson.fromJson(response.body().string(), ResponseResult.class);
```

Now,you can use it through the object responseResult.

Surely,There has more concisely way to deal with the problem. But I suggest you should master this way first.

Comment: @Developers I have edited the answer, Hope it can solve your problem.

Comment: I've ad a json that want so extract an ID friendly name and state... Is the same code to use?

Comment: They are similar. But I suggest you should learn to use `Gson` and how to convert string to `Javabean`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following json:

```
{
  "tag": "tg1",
  "version": "vr1"
}
```

Create a class which corresponds to the above.

```
data class TermsResponse(val tag: String, val version: String)
```

User `retrofit` to define your API:

```
@GET("/v1/myapi/terms")
Observable<Response<TermsResponse>> getTerms();
```

Use `okhttp` to make the api call:

```
    myApi.getTerms()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .subscribe(
                    { result -> showResult(result.body() as TermsResponse) },
                    { error -> showError(error.message) }
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for request

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {   
    private TextView mTextViewResult;    
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
        mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);
 
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
 
        String url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";
 
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
 
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
 
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    final String myResponse = response.body().string();
 
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mTextViewResult.setText(myResponse);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use `org.json.*` as written here: [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

One thing to note is that `response.body().string()` will work only once (as explained here: https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response-body/#the-response-body-can-be-consumed-only-once), so you could for example use that one chance to save the string body into a technical variable and then work with that.